# What is the significance of Prophet Yahya being "hasuwran"?

Tags: quran, arabic, prophets

Allah mentions in verse 39 of Surah Al-e-Imran:[image]

The fourth word from the end is "hasuwran" (حَصُورًا ), which Saheeh International (presumably accurately) translates as "abstaining (from women)."

Questions are:

- What exactly is the (complete) translation of this word?
- What is the significance of this property of Yahya (alayhi salaam)?

I read through a bunch of biography notes, but could not find any mention (let alone any relevance) to this specific word mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is what I know from [Tafsir Ibn Katheer](http://abdurrahman.org/qurantafseer/ibnkathir/ibnkathir_web/3.8167.html):

It says that ***"Hasuran"*** with respect to Yahya (alayhi salam) means he is immune to illegal sexual relations. That is what Allah has made him. It does not mean he refrains from sexual relations with women he marries (i.e. legal), but that he is immune from ***illegal*** sexual relations.

And Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 1):

It has been clear in Quran and Hadith that Allah loves those who refrain from adultery even when they are tempted to do so.

As mentioned in the "seven under the shade of Allah":

> ......a man who is called by a woman of beauty and position [for illegal intercourse], but be says: 'I fear Allaah'.....

There may be a story of the prophet (pbuh) that we have not heard about, such as that he refrained from adultery even when he was tempted to as the prophet yusuf (pbuh) did.

And Allah knows best.